# Magento 1.9 change grouped product page layout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, page

I'm new to Magento and try to play with layout of grouped product page.

Page I want to change layout, page link https://www.prorider.us/org/index.php/economy-bike-helmets-100.html

I create a grouped product with 4 associated products, and using Custom Design default/blank. Now I like to move the bike helmet images (quickview) to top of page, above associated products list. How to do that?

Comment: Try my answer and let me know

Answer (score 1):

go to backend catalog->product->selectyourproduct->design->custom layout update and write below code .

```
<reference  name="product.info">
   <action method="setTemplate"><template>yourTemplatePath/yourTemplate.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

or go to your theme local.xml or catalog.xml and write below code

```
 <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">  
     <reference  name="product.info">
         <action method="setTemplate"><template>yourTemplatePath/yourTemplate.phtml</template></action>
     </reference>
 </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I can not find "yourTemplate.phtml" under app/design/frontend/default, or make a new file?

Comment: yes make new file that you are talking to create

Comment: Have you tried  this??